# What would be the safest and quickest way to manipulate 25 views in Titanium

Tags: collections, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have 25 seperate views in Titanium, which are all created based on a model within a collection, like this:

```
tiles.each(function(tile){
    var tileView = Alloy.createController('board/tile', {
        tile: tile,
    });
    tile.controller = tileView;

    $.boardContainer.add(tileView.getView());
}
```

In this case, `tiles` is an Appcelerator Collection, and a `tile` is a model.

At a certain point in the logic of the app I need to call all 25 tiles, and hide a view.

What I currently do is loop through the collection again, and call a function exported in the view like this

```
function disableArrow(){
    $.arrow.visible = false;
    arrowsVisible = false;
}
exports.disableArrow = disableArrow;
```

This works, but is not very smooth, as when you have a slow device you can see the tiles rendering... What would be the best solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: Please see [Meta: Do you see what the \[appc\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314689/do-you-see-what-the-appc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a solution for what you try to achieve. If you need to manipulate 25 views than that's what needs to happen. You can't manipulate all of them at once.

The only thing you might be able to optimise is looping through them. You could - hacky - keep an array with direct references to all these `arrow` views and loop just through that instead of going through the controllers.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could use TableView in conjunction with data binding instead of creating a bunch of views manually.
Look here: [Alloy data binding](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding)
By the way, why are you creating 25 controllers when you need just views?

Comment: The views are in a grid, and they need to move around, sideways etc. So TableView is not an option. Also, each view has quite a lot of logic, so a controller is really needed, to self contain the logic.
So thanks, but this is no solution I'm afraid

Comment: Alloy data binding won't help but even give worse result because it would re-render the full table.